# Excel counting rows within an changing range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Morning

We log how many queries we get per day on different subjects and i want to create a quick formula that automatically counts them for us. CountA partly works if i make sure each topic has a set number of rows, but people keep deleting stuff, i can't stop them adding rows because some days they do have more queries on a topic. So i want to try and make the CountA start and stop between the specific words because the number of rows in each topic's range changes day to day.

So something like count all cells that have words below the word communities but stops counting once it gets to the word education

|Communities|

Comment: Try to provide a simple sample, it will easier for us to provide the solution.

Comment: A simple PivotTable to count or sum things in each subject could be an easy solution to this, and not dependent on sort order, deleted rows etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of sample data I will assume your queries are logged e.g. like this

```
Catergory    query#    name    description
Education    query1    name    details
Education    query2    name    details
Finance      query3    name    details
Education    query4    name    details
Community    query5    name    details
```

Then you can countif:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A100,"Education")
```

**Alternatively** if the data is sorted like this

```
Education 
Query1
Query2
Query3
Community
Query4
Query5
```

Then things are a little more difficult, especially if there is no blank row as a seperator. If there was or you can add one, use this to count until the next blank. Say you start this in B1 next to A1 / "Education"

```
=COUNTA(A2:INDEX(A2:A100,MATCH("",A2:A100,0)))
```

You can make A100 any number high enough as an upper limit.

The next best answer without a blank row, would require the order of the categories to be known, so you would need to change the "" in the above formula to say "Community" as the end stop for counting "Education". It would also count the end stop itself, so remember to substract 1 in the final formula.

The ultimate formula would need a new sheet, with all the categories listed in order in column A. Then MATCH formula in column B to find the start indexes for each category. Then counta with index to count from the start of one category to the start of the next category minus 1.

Comment: I cant work out the formatting properly to add the data you want. We get the data pretty basic. It's in one row of excel. It had a bold header with the subject. So COMMUNITIES, then under it is query 1, under that is query2, then the next subject is EDUCATION, then the queries go on a single row under that. The number of queries under each heading change on a daily basis depending on what's in the news. Hopefully that's helpful

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you both! Both do what I need.  Amazing

Comment: Kindly remember to checkmark the solution as the answer so others may know the question has been answered successfully.